# Why is my widget's listener not being notified when it's not in frame

Tags: flutter

As you'll see in the code below, I have a custom, sticky timer widget that, when stopped or reset, is supposed to update another custom widget I have further down the screen. The timer widget uses a TextEditingController to do this, which the second widget is listening to. This process works wonderfully and without error when both widgets are in frame, but when the second widget is more than just a little out of frame, it is not notified. It also doesn't give me any issues when I use a TextField instead of my custom widget. Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

For reference, this is the sticky widget I am using: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sticky_widgets

Code necessary to reproduce:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_sticky_widgets/flutter_sticky_widgets.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _controller = ScrollController();
  final _time = TextEditingController();
  List<Widget> getFifty() {
    List<Widget> l = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      l.add(
        const SizedBox(
          height: 40,
          child: Text("Placeholder"),
        ),
      );
    }
    return l;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          widget.title,
        ),
      ),
      body: StickyContainer(
        stickyChildren: [
          StickyWidget(
            initialPosition: StickyPosition(top: 300, left: 0),
            finalPosition: StickyPosition(top: 0, left: 0),
            controller: _controller,
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: 110,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 2.0),
              ),
              child: Flex(
                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                    fit: FlexFit.loose,
                    child: TimerWidget(
                      timerNum: 1,
                      onTimeSet: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _time.text = value;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        child: ListView(controller: _controller, children: [
          ...getFifty(),
          TimeEditWidget(
            controller: _time,
            timerNum: 1,
            onChanged: (value) {
              print('changed');
            },
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TimerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const TimerWidget({this.onTimeSet, this.timerNum, super.key});

  final void Function(String)? onTimeSet;
  final int? timerNum;

  @override
  State<TimerWidget> createState() => _TimerWidgetState();
}

class _TimerWidgetState extends State<TimerWidget> {
  Timer? _timer;
  int _ms = 0;
  int _seconds = 0;
  int _minutes = 0;
  String _btnText = "Start";
  String _time = "00:00.000";

  void startTimer() {
    if (_timer != null) {
      _timer!.cancel();
      _timer = null;
    } else {
      _timer = Timer.periodic(
        const Duration(milliseconds: 1),
        (Timer timer) => setState(
          () {
            _ms += 1;
            if (_ms == 1000) {
              _ms = 0;
              _seconds += 1;
            }
            if (_seconds == 60) {
              _seconds = 0;
              _minutes += 1;
            }
            if (_minutes == 100) {
              _minutes = 99;
              _seconds = 59;
              _ms = 999;
              _timer!.cancel();
            }
            setTime();
          },
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  void setTime() {
    _time =
        "${_minutes.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${_seconds.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}.${_ms.toString().padLeft(3, '0')}";
  }

  void toggleStart() {
    setState(() {
      _btnText = (_btnText == "Start") ? "Stop" : "Start";
    });
    startTimer();
    if (widget.onTimeSet != null && _btnText == "Start") {
      widget.onTimeSet!(_time);
    }
  }

  void reset() {
    if (_timer != null) {
      _timer!.cancel();
      _timer = null;
    }
    setState(() {
      _btnText = "Start";
      _minutes = 0;
      _seconds = 0;
      _ms = 0;
      setTime();
    });
    if (widget.onTimeSet != null) {
      widget.onTimeSet!(_time);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (_timer != null) {
      _timer!.cancel();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Flex(
      direction: Axis.vertical,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Text(
          (widget.timerNum == null) ? "Timer" : "Timer ${widget.timerNum}",
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
        ),
        Text(
          _time,
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            const Spacer(),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: toggleStart,
              child: Text(_btnText),
            ),
            TextButton(onPressed: reset, child: const Text("Reset")),
            const Spacer(),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class TimeEditWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const TimeEditWidget({this.timerNum, this.controller, this.onChanged, super.key});
  final TextEditingController? controller;
  final int? timerNum;
  final void Function(String value)? onChanged;

  @override
  State<TimeEditWidget> createState() => _TimeEditWidgetState();
}

class _TimeEditWidgetState extends State<TimeEditWidget> {
  final minuteController = TextEditingController();
  final secondController = TextEditingController();
  final millisecondController = TextEditingController();
  String mins = "00";
  String secs = "00";
  String ms = "000";

  void setTime() {
    print('alerted');

    String time = widget.controller!.text;
    mins = time.split(':')[0];
    secs = time.split(':')[1].split('.')[0];
    ms = time.split('.')[1];
    minuteController.text = mins;
    secondController.text = secs;
    millisecondController.text = ms;
    if (widget.onChanged != null) {
      widget.onChanged!('$mins:$secs.$ms');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (widget.controller != null) {
      widget.controller!.addListener(setTime);
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (widget.controller != null) {
      widget.controller!.removeListener((setTime));
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Text((widget.timerNum == null) ? "Time: " : "Time ${widget.timerNum}: "),
          CustomInput(
            validChars: "0123456789",
            maxLength: 2,
            height: 20,
            width: 20,
            controller: minuteController,
            onChanged: (value) {
              mins = value;
              if (widget.onChanged != null) {
                widget.onChanged!('$mins:$secs.$ms');
              }
            },
          ),
          const Text(":"),
          CustomInput(
            validChars: "0123456789",
            maxLength: 2,
            height: 20,
            width: 20,
            controller: secondController,
            onChanged: (value) {
              secs = value;
              if (widget.onChanged != null) {
                widget.onChanged!('$mins:$secs.$ms');
              }
            },
          ),
          const Text("."),
          CustomInput(
            validChars: "0123456789",
            maxLength: 3,
            height: 20,
            width: 27,
            controller: millisecondController,
            onChanged: (value) {
              ms = value;
              if (widget.onChanged != null) {
                widget.onChanged!('$mins:$secs.$ms');
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomInput extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomInput({
    required this.validChars,
    this.onChanged,
    this.height,
    this.width,
    this.maxLength,
    this.controller,
    super.key,
  });
  final int? maxLength;
  final TextEditingController? controller;
  final String validChars;
  final double? width;
  final double? height;
  final void Function(String value)? onChanged;

  @override
  State<CustomInput> createState() => _CustomInputState();
}

class _CustomInputState extends State<CustomInput> {
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
  String text = '';
  final _ts = GlobalKey<EditableTextState>();
  UnfocusDisposition disposition = UnfocusDisposition.scope;

  void setText() {
    print('changing');
    text = widget.controller!.text;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (widget.controller != null) {
      widget.controller!.addListener(setText);
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (widget.controller != null) {
      widget.controller!.removeListener((setText));
    }
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
      height: widget.height ?? 50,
      width: widget.width ?? 50,
      child: TapRegion(
        onTapOutside: (tap) {
          if (_focusNode.hasFocus) {
            setState(() {
              primaryFocus!.unfocus(disposition: disposition);
            });
          }
        },
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            if (!_focusNode.hasFocus && _focusNode.canRequestFocus) {
              _focusNode.requestFocus();
              if (_ts.currentState != null) {
                _ts.currentState!.requestKeyboard();
              }
            }
          },
          child: RawKeyboardListener(
            focusNode: _focusNode,
            child: Text(text),
            onKey: (value) {
              if (value.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.backspace) && text.isNotEmpty) {
                setState(() {
                  text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
                });
                if (widget.onChanged != null) {
                  widget.onChanged!(text);
                }
              } else {
                if (value.character != null && widget.validChars.contains(value.character!)) {
                  if (widget.maxLength == null || widget.maxLength! > text.length) {
                    setState(() {
                      text += value.character!;
                    });
                    if (widget.onChanged != null) {
                      widget.onChanged!(text);
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While the widget inside `ListView`, the widget doesn't hold the state once it is outside the viewport(+cacheExtent). As a result, you don't find the value on scrolling.

One easy approach be will be using `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`.

```dart
class _TimeEditWidgetState extends State<TimeEditWidget>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<TimeEditWidget> {
   
  ....

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Container(....);
  }
}
```

Comment: That solves half of my problem, which is that the state can be set after scrolling away, but this doesn't allow me to set the state of the widget _before_ I have scrolled to it. Thank you, btw.

Comment: Are you trying to get real-time update on bottom widget?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that, but I want the widget at the bottom of the screen to update regardless of whether I have scrolled to it or not. your solution will allow it to update after I have scrolled to it and then scrolled away, but it doesn't update it if I haven't scrolled down to the widget yet.